# how to show name box in listview title view after using drawitem?

Tags: c#, listview

As you know there is no simple way for changing selected item back color in listview control and for that you should use drawItem event. 
(Am I right or there is a way which I do not know?)
so, I use drawitem and try to make everything normal, except this property. it's good but in title view there is a small box after icon that show item name( also in large icon view),it's invisible but when I click on its location it shows. How should I make it visible always? thanks.

I added code and image,tanks for your response

```
    void FileList_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.Selected)
        {
            Rectangle rectangle = e.Bounds;
            rectangle.Inflate(-1, -1);

            Image image;

            if (this.View == System.Windows.Forms.View.LargeIcon || this.View == System.Windows.Forms.View.Tile)
            {
                image = LargeImageList.Images[e.Item.ImageKey];
            }
            else
            {
                image = SmallImageList.Images[e.Item.ImageKey];
            }

            Rectangle rectPoint = new Rectangle(e.Item.Bounds.X + 3, e.Item.Bounds.Y + 3, image.Width - 3, image.Height - 3);
            Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);

            using (Graphics g = e.Graphics)
            {
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, rectangle);

                g.DrawImage(image, rectPoint, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                Rectangle rectangle2 =new Rectangle(e.Item.Bounds.X+image.Width+5,e.Item.Bounds.Y+(image.Height/2)+7,50,15);
                using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat())
                {
                    using (Font headerFont =
                            new Font("Helvetica", 8, FontStyle.Regular))
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawString("Folder", headerFont,
                           Brushes.Black, rectangle2, sf);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            e.DrawDefault = true;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Post what you code you have tried so far on this.

Comment: It sounds like you arent taking e.state into consideration.  This is a guess since the code is not shown

Comment: Also tell us the View mode ! And add a few line breaks to the question, ok? Also: You do know that there are three relevant draw events, depending on the View ? did you call DrawText in the event??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done it somehow, first maybe you need to set each item text to string.Empty or something like that, then you should change rectangle for text yourself. it is not very good but it can be done in no time. for each view change and test until it be good.